# Erro ao instalar IDE Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: Erro Android Studio]

Sempre quando instalo o android Studio aparece esse erro:

```
execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidi'.
java.lang.IIIegalStateException:aidl is missing
```

já tentei fazer update e não resolve, gostaria de saber como concertá-lo. 
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Estará em falta instalar as buildtools da versão de SDK que escolheu como targetBuild. Ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766830/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugaidl-aidl-is-missing